# Processing large .txt file in Python works only on small files

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have several 1+ gb text files of URLs. I'm trying to use Python to find and replace in order to quickly strip down the URLs.

Because these files are big, I don't want to load them into memory.

My code works on small test files of 50 lines, but when I use this code on a big text file, it actually makes the file larger.

```
import re
import sys

def ProcessLargeTextFile():
    with open("C:\\Users\\Combined files\\test2.txt", "r") as r, open("C:\\Users\\Combined files\\output.txt", "w") as w:
        for line in r:
            line = line.replace('https://twitter.com/', '')
            w.write(line)
    return

ProcessLargeTextFile()
print("Finished")
```

Small files I tested my code with result in the twitter username (as desired)

> username_1
>
> username_2
>
> username_3

while large files result in

> https://twitter.com/username_1਍ഀ
>
> https://twitter.com/username_2਍ഀ
>
> https://twitter.com/username_3਍ഀ

Comment: are you sure that the large file where it's not behaving doesn't have a section like:  https://https://https://twitter.com/username_3

Comment: I'm betting if you pasted the exact inputs from your small files and large files, you'd likely see the difference yourself.  There's nothing overtly wrong with the code you included, so I'm guessing your inputs are different.  Look at (and show us) a specific line from the small file and a specific line from the large file.

Comment: Okay, so I need to add an if statement to check if its possible to line replace? My test file has non-uniform data, but it just skipped over the lines that didn't match

Comment: What you need, if you're going to ask a question about "why does my input give me this output," is to show the input.

Comment: I can upload the input file to some type of file host, but its too large to paste into pastebin or here lol. edit: Uploading now..

Comment: Ok.  At this point, I'm voting to close, as the question is poorly asked.  Show us one specific line that's causing your one specific error.  Don't show us the whole file.  Reproduce the problem with one specific line and show us that.

Comment: Scott, I don't know which specific line. Its a big ass file. I tested this code on a tiny file, >10,000 lines and it worked fine. On a much larger file, my output is no longer stripped, it comes out with little boxes after each line \

Comment: Input file for anyone who wants it https://uploadfiles.io/eyr7b

Comment: https://uploadfiles.io/eyr7b

Comment: Oh, I bet when you take the large file, chop out stuff to test and save it, it's changing the encoding of the file.  Like you are opening the file and it's UTF-16 or something and when it saves it saves as UTF-8.  Those little goofy boxes are sometimes an indication of encoding is the problem.  Try opening the big file, remove 1 line, save and see what happens.

Comment: @sniperd yes... I think that could be the issue, but I'm not sure why the http....com parts are still existing? Seems like they should be removed and the goofy boxes should come at the end of the username

Comment: I converted the input file to multiple different types and the same error is occuring

Comment: I'll grab the file and see what I can make it do.  I'm sick of this Visual Studio project I'm on, this is a welcome break :)

Comment: @sniperd haha, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with the encoding of the file, this works:

```
import re

def main():
    inputfile = open("1-10_no_dups_split_2.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-16")
    outputfile = open("output.txt", "a", encoding="UTF-8")
    for line in inputfile:
        line = re.sub("^https://twitter.com/", "", line)
        outputfile.write(line)
    outputfile.close()

main()
```

The trick being to specify UTF-16 on reading it, then output it as UTF-8.  And viola, the weird stuff goes away :)  I do a lot of work moving text files around with Python.  There are many setting you can do to play with the encoding to automatically replace certain characters and what not, just read up about the "open" command if you get into at weird spot, or post back here :).

Doing a quick look at the results, you'll probably want to have a few regexes so you can catch https://mobile.twitter.com/ and other stuff, but that's another story..  Good luck!

Comment: You're awesome... I spent hour+ trying encoding stuff, but never tried utf-16 and output utf-8.

Comment: I started a new job a few months ago and literally my first task was to write a generic cleaner in python to fixed text files....   I had run into this exact same problem (among others) which took me days to figure out.  The second I opened your example file I knew what it was!  :)  You are welcome, glad somebody else could benefit!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help! I was so close, with a few modifications of my original script I had it working for certain chunks of the file thanks to some try/excepts, what other sections were still breaking

Answer (score -1):

You can use the open() method's buffering parameter. 
Here is the code for it.

```
import re
import sys

def ProcessLargeTextFile():
    with open("C:\\Users\\Combined files\\test2.txt", "r",buffering=200000000) as r, open("C:\\Users\\Combined files\\output.txt", "w") as w:
        for line in r:
            line = line.replace('https://twitter.com/', '')
            w.write(line)
    return

ProcessLargeTextFile()
print("Finished")
```

So I am reading 20 MB of  data into memory at a time.

Comment: I think the OP's output file is larger, not the memory footprint being a problem

Comment: Yeah, the memory isn't the issue... its the output. I'm loading and reading and writing fine, the "writing" part of the big file just isn't the same as my test file's output.